# How to catch a signal in Rust without memory leaks

Tags: rust, memory-leaks, rust-tokio

I noticed memory leaks in my program and tracked it down to the signal handling. Seems crazy that there isn't a leak-free way to do this. I'm not worried about the "still reachable" bytes reported by Valgrind - I'm worried about the "possibly lost" bytes.

minimal reproducible example:

```
use tokio::signal;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

async fn sleep1() {
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("sleep1");
    }
}

async fn sleep2() {
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
        println!("sleep2");
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let s1 = Box::pin(sleep1());
    let s2 = Box::pin(sleep2());
    let sig = Box::pin(signal::ctrl_c());
    tokio::select! {
        _ = s1 => {},
        _ = s2 => {},
        _ = sig => {},
    };
    println!("shutting down");
    Ok(())
}
```

excerpt from Cargo.toml file:

```
edition = "2021"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

valgrind output:

```
==1366460== Command: target/debug/simulation
==1366460== 
sleep1
sleep2
sleep1
sleep1
^Cshutting down
==1366460== 
==1366460== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1366460==     in use at exit: 25,884 bytes in 82 blocks
==1366460==   total heap usage: 617 allocs, 535 frees, 145,635 bytes allocated
==1366460== 
==1366460== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1366460==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1366460==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1366460==      possibly lost: 1,188 bytes in 3 blocks
==1366460==    still reachable: 24,696 bytes in 79 blocks
==1366460==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1366460== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1366460== 
==1366460== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1366460== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: This almost feels like a bug report, so have you tried raising this with the developers who maintain Rust? If you join their Zulip community you'll probably get some attention asking about this.

Comment: @Bobulous - that's a good idea. i haven't communicated with the developers yet. i'll do that.

Comment: If the issue is with the signal handling, why would you bring it up to the Rust devs instead of the Tokio devs? If it is a Rust issue as seen through a Tokio API, then it's best for *them* to see it resolved. Regardless, I wouldn't be surprised if initializing a signal handler uses some global state (which wouldn't be cleaned up at exit).

Comment: I'm surprised, because I've run almost this very code through LLVM's ASAN for almost a year now and never got a leak report. I know that valgrind is not 100% compatible with tokio, so it might be a false positive of valgrind.

Comment: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues or https://discord.com/invite/tokio

Comment: I can confirm that the code you have does not contain a memory leak according to LLVM ASAN. It was able to detect `Box::leak()` properly when I added it.

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/1092

Comment: @kmdreko that's what I did. I raised the issue [here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/4756). I also devised a work-around. I wrote a C library to wait until a signal is called and I made a wrapper to call the library from Rust. it got rid of the "possible leaks".

Comment: If it's implementable in C, it's implementable in Rust. (unsafe Rust is a superset of C, as far as I know). The question is if one can cleanly integrate it in the Tokio library API without storing lazy statics. (which are the real reason for the warning, from my understanding)

Answer (score 0):

according to the tokio developers, this is a false positive resulting from the use of global variables. see [here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/4756).

also, I found that if one really wishes to get rid of the valgrind error, it's possible to [implement the signal handler in C](https://linuxhint.com/signal_handlers_c_programming_language/) and [call it from rust](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/c-with-rust.html). The rust program would spawn a blocking thread (something like `tokio::task::spawn_blocking`) that waits for the C code to catch a signal and terminate.